# $.ajax() not serving a request to fetch json from a static json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to fetch json data from a static .json file on an xampp server. I can do same with getJSON, but cannot from $.ajax(). Can someone point out the mistake?

```
$.ajax(function(){
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/example3/data.json',
      data: { patientID: "1" },
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(jsonData) {
        alert(jsonData);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error loading PatientID=' + id);
      }
});
```

Thanks in Advance! .. ;(

Comment: can you share the json?

Comment: How are you calling the AJAX? Any console errors?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to `post` to a static resource file

Comment: `function()` remove this....;)

Comment: getJSON uses a `GET` request. You are `POST`ing to a static file, which makes no sense. Try changing it to a `GET`. Also, the `$.ajax()` function expects a **Javascript object**, not a function definition. Remove the `function()` - it should just be $.ajax({...});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First parameter of $.ajax is not a function. 
Just give below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://fin.qfun.kr/index/a2',
    data: { patientID: "1" },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsonData) {
        alert(jsonData);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error loading PatientID=' + id);
    }
});
```